# Splitting text into a list of words with ICU

Tags: c++, utf-8, icu

I'm working on a text tokenizer. ICU is one of very few C++ libraries that have this feature, and probably the best maintained one, so I'd like to use it.
I've found the docs about `BreakIterator`, but there's one problem with it: how do I leave the punctuation out?

```
#include "unicode/brkiter.h"

#include <QFile>

#include <vector>

std::vector<QString> listWordBoundaries(const UnicodeString& s)
{
    UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
    BreakIterator* bi = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(Locale::getUS(), status);

    std::vector<QString> words;

    bi->setText(s);
    for (int32_t p = bi->first(), prevBoundary = 0; p != BreakIterator::DONE; prevBoundary = p, p = bi->next())
    {
        const auto word = s.tempSubStringBetween(prevBoundary, p);
        char buffer [16384];
        word.toUTF8(CheckedArrayByteSink(buffer, 16384));
        words.emplace_back(QString::fromUtf8(buffer));
    }

    delete bi;

    return words;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/ [])
{
    QFile f("E:\\words.TXT");
    f.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    QFile result("E:\\words.TXT");
    result.open(QFile::WriteOnly);

    const QByteArray strData = f.readAll();
    for (const QString& word: listWordBoundaries(UnicodeString::fromUTF8(StringPiece(strData.data(), strData.size()))))
    {
        result.write(word.toUtf8());
        result.write("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Naturally, the resulting file looks like this:

```
“
Come

outside
.

Best

if

we

do

not

wake

him
.
”
```

What I need is *just* the words. How can this be done?

Comment: What about [ispunct](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/ispunct/) function? You can check if the token is composed by one character, then take it as integer and check with that function.

Comment: @BiagioFesta: first, I have plenty non-ASCII characters here (like quotes). Second, a non-word won't necessarily be single-character (e. g. comma + space + opening quote).

Answer (score 2):

QT library include several useful methods for check the char's properties:
[QChar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qchar.html).

Indeed, you could create the *QString* variable from the *buffer*
and check all properties you need before to insert into the output vector.

For example:

```
auto token = QString::fromUtf8(buffer);
if (token.length() > 0 && token.data()[0].isPunct() == false) {
  words.push_back(std::move(token));
}
```

With that code I can access the first character of the string and check
whether it is a punctuation mark or not.

Something more robust, I express that as function:

```
bool isInBlackList(const QString& str) {
  const auto len = str.lenght();
  if (len == 0) return true;
  for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    const auto&& c = str.data()[i];
    if (c.isPunct() == true || c.isSpace() == true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If that function returns *true*, the token hasn't to be inserted into the vector.

Comment: This is not a bad idea at all. Although I only use Qt for convenience here and would like the final solution to rely only on ICU and stdlib. In other words, can I check a character for punctuation using only ICU?

Comment: ICU doesn't have any method of that type. At the moment I'm thinking about REGEX: [Regex Class ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classicu_1_1RegexMatcher.html). You can re-implement the function *isInBlackList* simply checking for punctuation in the string. If you need it, let me know and I'll edit the answer adding that kind of solution!

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to trouble you with that right now, perhaps a better solution will come up soon. And I also have performance reservations regarding regex. Would rather implement the black list as `std::set` of Unicode code points, but I don't want to have to fill this list manually - there are LOTS non-text Unicode characters, I can't possibly specify them all.